How to configure neovim with typescript-language-server and tsserver without using neovim plugins
For reasons not worth explaining, I have a context where I cannot easily install plugins. If it's absolutely needed, I can try, but chances are I'll be forced to use a different editor instead.
I've read quite a bit, so I am fairly familiar with what needs to be done at a high level. Problem is most guides are around Mason, mason-lspconfig and nvim-lspconfig, which I'm trying to avoid. I'm not being stubborn, I have a bad context.
The good news are:

Mason: I don't need it. Both typescript and typescript-language-server are available through npm
nvim-lspconfig: I don't need it. The docs say this plugin is just convenience. Meaning I should be able to do whatever this does manually (I reckon with a ton of effort though)
mason-lspconfig: I don't need it, as I wouldn't be using any of the above.

If I understood correctly, the next step is to start the server. I headed over to :help lsp and I got from there I need to call something like this
vim.lsp.start({
  name = 'tsserver',
  cmd = {'tsserver'},
  root_dir = vim.fs.dirname(vim.fs.find({'tsconfig.json', 'package.json'}, { upward = true })[1]),
})

I put the above in my init.lua, restarted, tried <C-X> <C-O> in insert mode, but nothing came up.
At this point, I have a bunch of questions:

Is it not working because I should somehow use typescript-language-server instead of tsserver in the config above?
Maybe it could be working, but I'm just missing some setup for omnifunc
Am I completely in the wrong path?

I have tried my best to find a guide or video where this manual setup is explained but have had no luck.
Could I get some guidance?
UPDATE
I found this line and have updated the command above with the following:
vim.lsp.start({
  name = 'my-server-name',
  cmd = {'typescript-language-server', '--stdio'},
  root_dir = vim.fs.dirname(vim.fs.find({'tsconfig.json', 'package.json'}, { upward = true })[1]),
})


I think the minimal required setup is described here: https://neovim.io/doc/user/lsp.html#lsp-quickstart

What does :lua =vim.lsp.get_clients() output?

Get the following erro: E5108: Error executing lua [string ":lua"]:1: attempt to call field 'get_clients' (a nil value) stack traceback:         [string ":lua"]:1: in main chunk

I fixed it by adding this code inside a function, as opposed to just leaving it in init.lua

The update part helped me thanks. However the file has been renamed and this is the new link. https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/lua/lspconfig/server_configurations/ts_ls.lua

@ChristopherFrancisco Is the "update" part the answer to your question? Could you move it to the answer space then?
